# guidance on authorizing users for functionality points

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, architecture, authorization

I'm developing an application using ASP.Net MVC 4 and need to be able to authorize users at a granular level - possibly data elements on a page, specific actions a user can take for a piece of data, etc.

I'm currently assigning a person to a role and that role is assigned a permission (view, add, edit, and delete) for an activity.  The role and permission value (I'm using bitwise values of the permission) is assigned to an activity.  I'm currently defining an activity as an action in my ASP.Net MVC app.  So, in order to navigate to a MVC action, the user has to have at least View permission for that action, otherwise they can't access the action.  What that user can do within that action depends on their other permissions (add, edit, delete).

This is an OK approach.  All of the permissions are stored in my database, so I've pretty much decoupled the permissions from the UI itself.  All I do is check to see if a user has say Add permission before showing a button to load a data entry form for example.

I'm pretty sure this approach is not going to be granular enough.  For example, if I need to hide a data column from User X in such and such role, then I'm not sure how to accommodate that requirement with my approach.  Right now the View permission is all or nothing.

I'm very very reluctant to inject a bunch of if statements in my view code controlling what is displayed to the user.  This is tightly coupling the UI to my security mechanism.  Not to mention you can't maintain this at all.

So, I'm stumped as to how to make a security mechanism more granular and yet maintain a nice clean separation.  When I think about this, I'm leaping directly from my current approach to injecting a bunch of if statements in my code.  I'm not seeing any alternatives.  Any advice, links to examples, etc. for best practices is much appreciated and needed.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what I was looking for is called claims based security.  .Net 4.5 has it baked in now.  Below is a great series of articles stepping you through the process:

[Introduction to Claims based security](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/02/11/introduction-to-claims-based-security-in-net4-5-with-c-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not make this approach more granular. All existing access control paradigms are based on assumption that resource is something solid and cannot be divided (Files are good example of this). Otherwise it would be very overcomplicated and scary.

The problem is that you mix permissions of different nature into the same framework. First type is 'who can access resources?', the second type is 'who should see this part of resource?'.

My suggestion is making additional extra `data filtering layer`.

It can use existing same roles-permissions assignments structure, or even extend it. Functionally this new layer and the main access control should be independent on each other. If you turn off one of them, the remaining system should continue working normally.

Such "role-base data filtering" sub-system should be carefully planned depending on the situation. In asp.net mvc filtering can be made at two levels:

1. Data access. When data is read from DB, some part of it is concealed depending on access.
2. Presentation. In a simplest way different views render different levels of data access. Complicated way is using custom HtmlHelper extensions - which call that new sub-system to check access while rendering.

---

Small update:

As access control systems' main focus are 'objects', probably you could think on what you understand as 'object'. For example, an object field (column) can be considered. Such a shift would be a fundamental change and bring complexity of course, but it could implement most of your requirements.

This would work similar to SQL, where a user should specify columns required, and system checks columns access before request execution, so probably you'd want to research how it's done there.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the feedback.  Do you have any links you can share please for further reading?

Comment: It was a part of university studies with too many theory, mostly based on Orange book - http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/secpubs/rainbow/std001.txt . I'd also suggest read through "Access control" article and find something that would be useful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control .